# Enable and add CSS Class for all the input elements inside a HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with input type="text" elements in some of the TDs and the table have multiple rows (not more than 5) with the same structure.

Is there a way to enable and add some CSS classes to all the input elements in the table using jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, there is. What 'CSS classes' do you want to add? When? In response to what event or situation?

Comment: The textfields are initially in a disable state with white background. I have a CSS class to set the text field background when in editing mode. There is an edit button in the page and when clicked on it, the text field should become enabled and the background be changed indicating that its ready for editing. 

@David Thomas, I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply

```
$("table input").addClass("yourClassName");
```

will do the trick. All input fields that comes under table tag will now have a class "yourClassName"

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table input").attr('disabled','disabled').addClass('classes');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('table tr td').find('input:text').each(function(){
$(this).prop('disabled',false); // this line enable the text box
$(this).addClass('urclass'); // this line add the class to text box
});
```

OR

```
$('table tr td').find('input:text').prop('disabled',false).addClass('urclass');
```

Comment: Why are you using `each()` and not just chaining the `prop()` and `addClass()` methods to the selector?

Comment: table have multipe rows and inputs

Comment: SridharR: so? @oGeez: don't *all* jQuery methods (used as setters) affect all elements matched by the selector? It's only when used as getters that they affect only the first, I think.

Comment: @DavidThomas I literally just went through that thought process myself after leaving the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table td input:text').addClass('yourClass').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way :

```
$('table').find('input:text').prop('disabled',false).addClass('urclass');
```